# Horizontal differential form

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms, vector-bundles

Let $\mathcal{E}$ be a vector bundle over $M$. A horizontal differential form on $\mathcal{E}$ is a differential form $\alpha$ such that $\iota(X) \alpha = 0$ for all vertical vector fields X.

My question (sorry if it is trivial) is: why such a differential form is called horizontal not vertical ?

Comment: To give you some idea about the terminology, since it vanishes on all vertical vector fields, it means that the only directions that survive are the horizontal, hence the name.

Comment: A horizontal form is one that is the pullback of a form on the base manifold.